# Interpretation of $W(J)$ in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In Zee's Quantum Field Theory in a nutshell, he discusses the quantity $W(J)$, where

$$\left<0\middle| e^{-iHT} \middle|0\right> = e^{-iET} = Ce^{iW(J)}$$

and for a free theory with a source $J = J_1 + J_2$ where $J_1$ and $J_2$ are localized in space, we have

$$W(J) = -\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}J_2^*(k) \frac{1}{k^2-m^2+i\varepsilon}J_1(k)$$

From here he says that there is a resonance peak at $k^2 = m^2$, the energy-momentum relationship for a particle and says that we interpret the physics as the following:

> "In region 1 in spacetime there exists a source that sends out a 'disturbance in the field,' which is later absorbed by a sink in region 2 in spacetime."

I do not understand how you can come up with the explanation. Where we get that there is a disturbance/a particle that *moves* and is created and absorbed?

Answer (score 1):

If you purely look at the integrand, then it looks like a Feynman diagram as follows:
a particle is created at x_1, propagates through space and gets absorbed at x_2. This is apparent from the structure of the integrand: source - propagator - source* = sink.
The integral just means your integrating over all possible particle momenta and summing those results to get the total rate at which this event happens.